# Highcharts and highmaps plugin render a blank map

Tags: javascript, highcharts

so here is code :

```js
var data = [
    ['tn-4431', 0],
    ['tn-sf', 1],
    ['tn-me', 2],
    ['tn-to', 3],
    ['tn-mn', 4],
    ['tn-bj', 5],
    ['tn-ba', 6],
    ['tn-bz', 7],
    ['tn-je', 8],
    ['tn-nb', 9],
    ['tn-tu', 10],
    ['tn-kf', 11],
    ['tn-ks', 12],
    ['tn-gb', 13],
    ['tn-gf', 14],
    ['tn-sz', 15],
    ['tn-sl', 16],
    ['tn-mh', 17],
    ['tn-ms', 18],
    ['tn-kr', 19],
    ['tn-ss', 20],
    ['tn-za', 21],
    ['tn-kb', 22],
    ['tn-ta', 23]
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'countries/tn/tn-all'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/tn/tn-all.js">Tunisia</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/tn/tn-all.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

since I am using already Highcharts.js to render line charts and polar chart in my code i can't use highmaps . I followed the general documentation for Highcharts  maps and installed the plugin for highcharts maps. the code was fine 1 day ago and it render the map but now it is showing me this error in the chrome console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataMin' of undefined".
is there any solution ? 
thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce your code and seems that everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cjr9p7oq/

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
   ...
});
```

It could be a temporary issue related to binding files after the new release. Please confirm if everything works fine.

Comment: sorry it is not working , it still render a blank map.

Comment: Even the demo which I shared render a blank map?

Comment: Try to clean the cache on your browser or test it in the incognito mode. There was a temporary issue related to deploying modules - it behaved like one module is from the previous version, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/afq5ykvm/

Comment: my code is working now after clearing the cache thank you very much, but the jsFiddle is still not working i don't know why ,this is what is showing me https://imgur.com/02IwapA .
thanks anyways

Comment: same problem https://weather.town/forecast/united-states/new-york/new-york-city/

Comment: @moledet I am not sure if the problem is related - I checked the dev console while loading your website and some errors occur while rendering the map. I am not sure what causes the error- you should try to debug it more.